# Detect Circle in Low Contrast Images

Tags: opencv

I have a bunch of low contrast images of white LEGO parts and pieces as shown. Since it has very low contrast and most of the edge detection algorithm does not perform well. The particular edge I need is the outermost circumference.

I tried applying some filters, but these images clearly need some pre-processing. Could you please suggest what I could do to get better results. I tried searching online but the solutions I found either don't work or sound like magic to me.

[LEGO PARTS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX5yv.jpg)

[THE EDGE I NEED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54ONu.jpg)

Comment: what did you try and how do the results look? I would recommend a raw Sobel as a first try.

Comment: see https://answers.opencv.org/question/235957/measuring-the-diameter-of-circles/

Answer (score 0):

Doing contrast stretching could help in low contrast images. see the opencv documentation for more information from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc1/tutorial_basic_linear_transform.html).